# Вывести переменную внутри объекта

Tags: javascript

Как вывести переменную `fullName` ? Почему этот код не работает и не выводится "Bob Ross"?

```js
var Person = function(firstAndLast) {
  var fullName = firstAndLast;
  this.getFullName = function() {
    return fullName;
  };
  return firstAndLast;
};

var bob = new Person('Bob Ross');
console.log(bob.getFullName());
```

Мне важно завести переменную `fullName` именно таким способом и никаким другим.

Comment: все работает прекрасно....

Comment: Да, действительно)) Нашел ошибку в куске кода, который не привел здесь, поэтому не работало.